# Как преобразовать строку так, чтобы можно было над ним выполнять арифметические операции

Tags: javascript

Суть скрипта заключается в том, что при вводе на поле prompt n-количество символов отображалось в прогрессирующейся манере, но вот теперь нужно его регрессировать в обратном порядке.

```
var empty = "";
var symbol = "*";
var count = prompt("Enter any number");
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    empty = empty + symbol;
    console.log(empty); 

    if (i == 10) {
        // здесь скорее будет регрессия символов
    }
}
```

Пример так выглядит:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

когда пытаюсь вычесть один символ, к примеру результат последней строки, где 
`empty typeof - String (этот тип строка) 
"**********"

empty - empty или
empty - 1`,

то интерпретатор выдает 
результат NaN (извиняюсь прежде написал Null)

Уважаемые знатоки, как же строку тогда преобразовать так, чтобы я мог регрессировать эти символы в обратом порядке. Я подозреваю, что это строка должна преобразоваться в массив(это только мое предположение). Благодарю заранее за ответ

Comment: *когда пытаюсь вычесть один символ* Как именно?

Comment: ********* - этот тип строка, Вбейте его в консоль, а потом попробуйте вычесть хотя бы один символ 
вам ИНТЕРПРЕТАТОР скажет NaN

Comment: Сначала надо преобразовать строку в массив. Что-то вроде `let arr = empty.split('');`, а затем `arr.pop();`. По идее это должно решить задачу.

Comment: *а потом попробуйте вычесть хотя бы один символ* Повторяю: КАК??? код показывайте... а то, знаете ли, для строкового типа операция вычитания как бы не существует...

Comment: @Akina вот в этом и вопрос, как его преобразовать, чтоб над ними можно было выполнять  арифметические операции, если никак, то нет решений видимо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо работать со строкой, оператор математической операции `-` пытается привести строку к `Number` и получает в итоге `NaN` т.к. входная последовательность не может быть интерпретирована как число;

Самый простой способ, сделать то что Вы хотите - [брать подстроку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
symbol = symbol.substring(1);
```

причем в Вашем конкретном случае можно "откусывать" символы с начала строки.

```js
var symbol = "*******";
for (var i = symbol.length; i > 1; i--) {
    symbol = symbol.substring(1);
    console.log(symbol); 
}
```

Или с конца:

```
symbol = symbol.substring(0, symbol.length - 1);
```

```js
var symbol = "*******";
for (var i = symbol.length; i > 1; i--) {
    symbol = symbol.substring(0, symbol.length-1);
    console.log(symbol); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let n = 5
const s = '*'

while (n > 0)
  console.log (s.repeat (n--))
```